# Backbone.Collection.reset() throws an exception in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

Every time, I'm resetting a Backbone.Collection in a Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView, IE8 throws an error:

> Function.prototype.apply: argument is null or undefined

The same case applies to emptyView.

My CoffeeScript code (js version below):

```
Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend
url       : '/videos.json'
baseModels: []
initialize : -> 
  GIS.VL.vent.on 'specialization:selected', @onSpecializationSelected, @
  @on 'reset', @onFirstSync, @

onFirstSync : (a)->
  @off 'reset', @onFirstSync, @
  @baseModels = @models
  console.log @models

onSpecializationSelected : (model)-> 
  if model.id < 0
    @reset @baseModels
  else
    filteredItems = _.filter @baseModels, (item)->
      specializations = _.map item.get('specializations'), (specialization) ->
        specialization.id 
      -1 < _.lastIndexOf specializations, model.id
    @reset filteredItems
```

Javascript version:

```
var Collection;

Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/videos.json',
  baseModels: [],
  initialize: function() {
    GIS.VL.vent.on('specialization:selected', this.onSpecializationSelected, this);
    return this.on('reset', this.onFirstSync, this);
  },
  onFirstSync: function(a) {
    this.off('reset', this.onFirstSync, this);
    this.baseModels = this.models;
    return console.log(this.models);
  },
  onSpecializationSelected: function(model) {
    var filteredItems;
    if (model.id < 0) {
      return this.reset(this.baseModels);
    } else {
      filteredItems = _.filter(this.baseModels, function(item) {
        var specializations;
        specializations = _.map(item.get('specializations'), function(specialization) {
          return specialization.id;
        });
        return -1 < _.lastIndexOf(specializations, model.id);
      });
      return this.reset(filteredItems);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm using the simples possible CollectionView, with Handlebars templates:

```
  VideosView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend
    tagName   : 'div'
    itemView  : VideoView
    collection: new Collection
    config: 
      itemsPerPage: 3

    initialize: (options)->
      console.log 'initialize'

      # override defaults:
      @config           = _.extend @config, options
```

Javascript version below:

```
var VideosView;

VideosView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  itemView: VideoView,
  collection: new Collection,
  config: {
    itemsPerPage: 3
  },
  initialize: function(options) {
    console.log('initialize');
    return this.config = _.extend(this.config, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: which line of code in your app is causing this? also, please supply a stack tract that points back to the line in Marionette that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Marionette, calling `.apply` with a null or undefined `arguments` parameter.

Marionette and it's dependencies have been updated to fix this, and the fix is not sitting int he dev branch (see this ticket: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/368 ).

If you need this fix immediately, you'll need to grab the marionette build from the `dev` branch: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/tree/dev/lib

If you're using the "core" build, be sure to update Wreqr and EventBinder as well. BabySitter did not need any updates.

Comment: Works like magic, thank you sooo much! I've been banging my head against the keyboard for over 2 days trying to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that *all* of your objects have no stray commas:

```
ie8err: { something: 1, something: 2, } //Error in IE8 and below.
```

I'm not positive that's it, but it smells like it might be.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked, I wish it was that simple... but thank you anyway:)